# Comparing text in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can we compare the text entered in `UITextVIew` with my default text in code to determine whether they are both the same or not?

Comment: do some search man... fairly simple answer..

Comment: Do you want it as case sensitive compare or case insensitive? Either ways I have provided both ways in my answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

Though this is a case sensitive comparison of string

```
 BOOL boolVal = [textView.text isEqualToString:@"My Default Text"];
```

Here is how you can do case insensitive comparison of string:

```
BOOL boolVal = [textView.text compare:@"My Default Text" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]
```

Here if `boolVal` is `YES` then you can say that strings are same else they are different.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: When writing code, format it as code. Try to write in a proper english, and don't write stuff like "Thanks", etc at the end of your post.

Comment: Your first post was very low quality, that's the only reason why I posted another answer. Nothing personal.

Comment: Please don't argue in comments. Enter the chat if you have something personal to say.

Comment: **I think people who downvote should always write a comment below why they are down voting the answer**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the methods of [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for this.

**1:** `isEqualToString`: (case-sensitive)

```
if( [ myString isEqualToString: otherString ] )
{}
```

**2:** `caseInsensitiveCompare`: (case-insensitive)

```
if( [ myString caseInsensitiveCompare: otherString ] )
{}
```

**3:** `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare`: (case-insensitive and localized)

```
if( [ myString localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: otherString ] )
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

First is to compare with the value abc and second is to compare with the `String * str`.

```
[textfield1.text isEqualToString:@"abc"]
```

or

```
[textfield1.text isEqualToString:str];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if([textfield.text isEqualToString:yourtext])
{
   //true;
}
else
{
//false
}
```