# Comparing Strings in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm writing a small app for the iphone and I'm trying to write a function that will insert an NSMutableString into an NSArray in alphabetical order. Also I'll be writing a sort to sort the entire array as well. For both cases I'm wondering what the best way of comparing NSMutableStrings is. Is there a specific function I can use?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to do a one time sort or sort while inserting?

Comment: Another issue is that you can't insert into an `NSArray`, you need an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @Jonathan: Did neither of the 6 answers help you?

Comment: Oh yes, most of them were actually helpful. I voted those ones up, but haven't really had time to try them out yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
(NSComparisonResult)[aString compare: bString];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:

You can use this or one of the related methods if you're doing insertion sort. However, if you want to do a one time sort of the NSMutableArray, you can use one of the NSMutableArray sorting methods such as `sortUsingComparator:`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator:

Answer (score 2):

If you look under ["Identifying and comparing strings" in the NSString reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW29), you'll find several options. They do slightly different things, since you might want to compare strings in different ways (e.g. are numbers compared in lexical or numeric order?). The most basic is `compare:` — you can probably start there and choose a more complicated version as needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you. This is my answer which I have taken from the link:

[Comparing text in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352466/comparing-text-in-uitextview/8352541#8352541)

**SOLUTION-1:** I have modified it here a bit to make it more easier for your case:

Let us assume String1 is one NSString.

```
 //Though this is a case sensitive comparison of string
 BOOL boolVal = [String1 isEqualToString:@"My Default Text"];

 //Here is how you can do case insensitive comparison of string:
 NSComparisonResult boolVal = [String1 compare:@"My Default Text" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]; 

 if(boolVal == NSOrderedSame)
 {
     NSLog(@"Strings are same");
 }
 else
 {
     NSLog(@"Strings are Different");
 }
```

> Here if boolVal is NSOrderedSame then you can say that strings are same else they are different.

**SOLUTION-2:** Also you don't find this easy, you can refer to **Macmade's answer** under the same link.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

For sorting array

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

try `BOOL ans = [str1 isEqualToString:str2];`

Comment: That's just about the only string comparison function I know. the only problem is I need to know which string is greater in the case that they're not equal.

Comment: Which string is **greater** ? What do you mean by greater ?

Answer (score 1):

Try `NSArray`'s `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method:

```
NSArray * stringArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"dddsss", @"aada", @"bbb", nil];
[stringArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog(@"%@", [stringArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]);
```

Out put:

```
(
  aada,
  bbb,
  dddsss
)
```

What's more, you can use `NSSortDescriptor` to decide ASC or DESC order.