# Trying to work with NSString but I'm having problems comparing two strings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have a simple program that I'm testing a printer class in.

```
-(void) setInkType {
    NSMutableString *theInkType;
    InkType typeOfInk;
    char inkFromInput[50];

    NSLog(@"What type of ink are you using?");
    NSLog(@"Options are photoInk, lazerJet, regularInk");
    fgets(inkFromInput,50,stdin);
    theInkType = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithUTF8String:inkFromInput];
    NSLog(@"%@",theInkType);

    if([theInkType compare: @"photoInk"]==true) {
        typeOfInk.photoInk = 564;
        NSLog(@"Your using a photo ink of type %d",typeOfInk.photoInk);
        inkType.photoInk = typeOfInk.photoInk;
    }
    else { if ([theInkType compare: @"lazerJet"] == true) {
        typeOfInk.lazerJet = 94;
        NSLog(@"Your using a lazer toner of type %d",typeOfInk.lazerJet);
        inkType.lazerJet = typeOfInk.lazerJet;
    }

    else { if  ([theInkType compare: @"regularInk"] == true) {
        typeOfInk.regularInk = 910;
        NSLog(@"Your using a regular ink of type %d",typeOfInk.regularInk);
        inkType.regularInk = typeOfInk.regularInk;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

When I run this I can enter in "photoInk" and "lazerInk" and I get a proper output. Why is it when I type "regularInk" I get a bad output?

I'm thinking it could be my {}'s but I'm not quite sure. I've been scratching my head for a few hours at this.

If there is anymore Cocoa flavoring I can do to make this look smoother let me know too please.

Answer (score 3):

`-compare:` doesn't return a boolean true/false value, it returns an `NSComparisonResult`, which is either `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame`, or `NSOrderedDescending`.

So you could do this:

```
if ([theInkType compare: @"photoInk"] == NSOrderedSame)
```

But really, the `-isEqual:` method is closer to your true intention.

```
if ([theInkType isEqual: @"photoInk"])
```

Also: you're doing your `else` clauses wrong. Not this:

```
if (x) {
    ...
}
else { if (y) {
    ...
} }
```

But this:

```
if (x) {
    ...
} else if (y) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Cool I got it to work, I realized that my first string from the input tags a \n onto the end of the word. I had to strip that off. I've noticed that isEqual and isEqualToString when used on any of the options still work. Whats the difference?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:), `isEqualToString:` is just a slightly (VERY slightly) faster way to check equality, if you know both objects are strings. `isEqual:` works with arbitrary objects of any type, so it has to do a type check first. In reality you would never notice the speed difference unless you were doing the check a million times.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you. This is my answer which I have taken from the link:

[Comparing text in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352466/comparing-text-in-uitextview/8352541#8352541)

**SOLUTION-1:** I have modified it here a bit to make it more easier for your case:

Let us assume String1 is one NSString.

```
 //Though this is a case sensitive comparison of string
 BOOL boolVal = [String1 isEqualToString:@"My Default Text"];

 //Here is how you can do case insensitive comparison of string:
 NSComparisonResult boolVal = [String1 compare:@"My Default Text" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]; 

 if(boolVal == NSOrderedSame)
 {
     NSLog(@"Strings are same");
 }
 else
 {
     NSLog(@"Strings are Different");
 }
```

> Here if boolVal is NSOrderedSame then you can say that strings are same else they are different.

**SOLUTION-2:** Also you don't find this easy, you can refer to **Macmade's answer** under the same link.

Hope this helps you.

Hope this helps you.